# External drive installed driver but not detected on my computer

Tags: windows-8, drivers, external-hard-drive

I recently installed windows 8. Everything is working fine but when I plugged in my external drive, the driver gets detected and installed but I cant see it in my computer. And when I checked on the device manager, here's the properties it shows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This shows that the drive is attached and recognized, but there are no partitions available.

To use this device you will need to format it - you can do so by right clicking `Computer` / `This PC` -> `Manage` -> `Disk Management`.

The the tree of the device, all of the partitions should be listed. From here you can right click on the device itself and click `Format`.

If this drive was used previously on another system, such as OSX, or any other Unix build - it may infact already be partitioned and formatted, however in a format this is not recognized by windows.

If my steps are unclear or you are unsure what to do, please edit your original question and include some additional screenshots from the screens that I have directed you to.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me to notice that the disk became unallocated. I recovered the partition using an external software.